# cmd output partially redirected C#

Tags: c#

I'm redirecting `cmd` output as per below:

```
name.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(StandardOutputHandler);
```

The problem is when `CMD` contains a "call" command to another bat file.

When I run bat manually, all works fine and content from call is visible in `cmd` window. However, when running via `Winforms` the output from call is not redirected(not appearing in the console for example).

```
:: Call Job/Sytem variables

call Test_Variables.bat
```

The Test_Variables bat contains simple set instructions for variables:

```
set SYSTEM=%JOB%\System\
```

Is there a way to have it included in the redirected output?

using Visual studio 2015 and running winform application.

Comment: This might not solve your problem, but in the past I have used ConsoleControl https://github.com/dwmkerr/consolecontrol  to do what I required when displaying data from Console Applications.  You could look into this.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith thanks for the suggestion but the source code behind is very similar to what I have and therefore I think I will have the same problem. I'm guessing it must be reading the content of the called bat into memory or something and it's added before output is redirected. Bit this is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of the problem(with some help).

To redirect output I need to set UseShellExecute to false and therefore call command will not be invoked when output is redirected.

The only way around it is to read the call file manually :(

Hope this helps someone.